# YCSB get stuck when working with Cassandra

Tags: ycsb

The command I use:

```
sudo bin/ycsb run cassandra-cql -P workloads/workloadf -P cassandra.dat -s > outputs/runf-2.dat 2> outputs/log-runf-2.txt
```

And:

```
tail -f outputs/log-runf-2.txt
```

But the log stuck at:

```
2021-08-16 17:36:38:255 7850 sec: 65373659 operations; 6141.2 current ops/sec; est completion in 1 hour 9 minutes [READ: Count=61414, Max=1200127, Min=265, Avg=4892.3, 90=1040, 99=168191, 99.9=544255, 99.99=799743] [READ-MODIFY-WRITE: Count=30620, Max=986111, Min=472, Avg=5108.82, 90=1557, 99=153087, 99.9=481279, 99.99=762367] [UPDATE: Count=30634, Max=63551, Min=166, Avg=484.96, 90=550, 99=737, 99.9=14887, 99.99=44991]
2021-08-16 17:36:48:255 7860 sec: 65435896 operations; 6223.7 current ops/sec; est completion in 1 hour 9 minutes [READ: Count=62232, Max=1267711, Min=300, Avg=4969.52, 90=1029, 99=150399, 99.9=586239, 99.99=946175] [READ-MODIFY-WRITE: Count=31050, Max=1258495, Min=541, Avg=5495.38, 90=1544, 99=156543, 99.9=572927, 99.99=950271] [UPDATE: Count=31044, Max=94847, Min=152, Avg=486.59, 90=544, 99=730, 99.9=16095, 99.99=54623]
2021-08-16 17:36:58:255 7870 sec: 65501151 operations; 6525.5 current ops/sec; est completion in 1 hour 9 minutes [READ: Count=65256, Max=2203647, Min=233, Avg=4650.72, 90=1016, 99=151935, 99.9=532479, 99.99=888319] [READ-MODIFY-WRITE: Count=32585, Max=2203647, Min=368, Avg=5292.65, 90=1524, 99=151295, 99.9=549375, 99.99=909823] [UPDATE: Count=32576, Max=87935, Min=132, Avg=485.37, 90=542, 99=726, 99.9=15343, 99.99=55423]
2021-08-16 17:37:08:255 7880 sec: 65559502 operations; 5835.1 current ops/sec; est completion in 1 hour 9 minutes [READ: Count=58354, Max=1277951, Min=313, Avg=5203.44, 90=1037, 99=176767, 99.9=634367, 99.99=939519] [READ-MODIFY-WRITE: Count=29259, Max=1217535, Min=563, Avg=5589.22, 90=1547, 99=172031, 99.9=627711, 99.99=916479] [UPDATE: Count=29247, Max=76863, Min=183, Avg=480.89, 90=545, 99=733, 99.9=17087, 99.99=57279]
2021-08-16 17:37:18:255 7890 sec: 65614920 operations; 5541.8 current ops/sec; est completion in 1 hour 8 minutes [READ: Count=55415, Max=1049599, Min=199, Avg=5494.55, 90=1047, 99=192383, 99.9=639999, 99.99=934911] [READ-MODIFY-WRITE: Count=27552, Max=1030143, Min=326, Avg=5864.25, 90=1571, 99=184319, 99.9=578047, 99.99=915455] [UPDATE: Count=27567, Max=773631, Min=113, Avg=551.14, 90=553, 99=742, 99.9=26751, 99.99=111295]
```

It didn't show any error or warning but stopped printing log.

I check the ycsb process:

```
ps auwx | grep ycsb
```

The result:

```
ran       93177  0.0  0.0  13144  1048 pts/2    S+   18:10   0:00 grep --color=auto ycsb
```

Comment: It seems like the experiment ended.